# Scope of variable when passed to another function in python decorators

Tags: python, scope, decorator

So I was reading this [wonderful piece](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/11/29/improve-your-python-decorators-explained/) which tries to explain decorators in python.

My question is specific to this code snippet.

```
def surround_with(surrounding):
    """Return a function that takes a single argument and."""
    def surround_with_value(word):
        return '{}{}{}'.format(surrounding, word, surrounding)
    return surround_with_value

def transform_words(content, targets, transform):
    """Return a string based on *content* but with each occurrence 
    of words in *targets* replaced with
    the result of applying *transform* to it."""
    result = ''
    for word in content.split():
        if word in targets:
            result += ' {}'.format(transform(word))
        else:
            result += ' {}'.format(word)
    return result

markdown_string = 'My name is Jeff Knupp and I like Python but I do not own a Python'
markdown_string_italicized = transform_words(markdown_string, ['Python', 'Jeff'],
        surround_with('*'))
print(markdown_string_italicized)
```

What I don't understand is how did the function `surround_with()` get the variable `word` (when passed on by `transform(word)` inside `transform_words()`) in it's scope? I mean we have only declared a holding variable (as a function argument) for what the surrounding value should be and nothing else. Then how was `word` available to it?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Note that, inside `transform_words`, the function `surround_with_value` **is** `transform`. So when we call `transform(word)`, we're actually calling `surround_with_value(word)`, because those two names refer to the same function *(not quite, actually, as `surround_with_value` goes out of scope when `surround_with` ends, but this is the easiest way to think about it)*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That makes sense, I posted an answer based on my understanding, can you check for its correctness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `surround_with()` function returns another function object with a *closure*:

```
def surround_with(surrounding):
    """Return a function that takes a single argument and."""
    def surround_with_value(word):
        return '{}{}{}'.format(surrounding, word, surrounding)
    return surround_with_value
```

So `surround_with_value` is returned; it is this function that prepends and appends the value of `surrounding` to whatever is passed in:

```
>>> def surround_with(surrounding):
...     """Return a function that takes a single argument and."""
...     def surround_with_value(word):
...         return '{}{}{}'.format(surrounding, word, surrounding)
...     return surround_with_value
...
>>> function = surround_with(' foo ')
>>> function
<function surround_with_value at 0x108ac16e0>
>>> function('bar')
' foo bar foo '
```

The `surround_with_value()` function was returned and a reference to it was stored in the name `function`. That function object references `surrounding` as a *closure*:

```
>>> function.__closure__
(<cell at 0x108a8a590: str object at 0x1074c4060>,)
>>> function.__closure__[0].cell_contents
' foo '
```

and each time you call it that closure is dereferenced and the contents are used.

So `surround_with()` produces a function object, and such function (as the result of `surround_with('*')`), is passed to `transform_words()` as the 3rd argument:

```
transform_words(markdown_string, ['Python', 'Jeff'],
        surround_with('*'))
```

so it is assigned to the variable `transform`:

```
def transform_words(content, targets, transform):
```

Thus, each time you call `transform`, you really are calling the nested `surround_with_value()` function with `'*'` as the `surrounding` closure, and `word` is being passed in:

```
result += ' {}'.format(transform(word))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood it,

When we call `surround_with('*')`, it returns the function `surround_with_value()` which is then returning the value `'{}{}{}'.format('*', word, '*')`.

Now the very same function takes an argument (`word` here) which is then passed inside `transform_words()` and renamed as `transform()`.

Inside it we finally pass the value for `word`.

Comment: That's pretty much it, yes!

Answer (score 0):

Closure can be very confusing and this example might not be the best to show **why** surround_with_value() **remembers** surround with(surrounding) event if it's not in its scope.

I strongly advice you to read this excellent blog showing all concept you need to understand to understand decorators. Step1: Scope-->Step2: Closure-->Step3: Decorators

Take some time and read it from the beginning.
http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/